# Timed out after 30000ms when I tried to go next page by clicking Submit button using Selenium RC

Tags: java, click, timeout, automated-tests, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC by java. Fill up necessary data on 1st page-->`Click` Submit button to go next page. My code is:

```
selenium.click("Submit");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

After clicking Submit button I found the error:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms
```

Can anybody pls help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timed out after 30000ms when I try to go next page by clicking Submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164638/timed-out-after-30000ms-when-i-try-to-go-next-page-by-clicking-submit-button)

Comment: You posted virtually the same question an hour earlier.  Don't repost your questions in an attempt to get people to answer them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Selenium.waitforpagetoload("30000");

means you are giving time **30000 m.s= 30 seconds**

It means your page is taking more than 30 seconds to load completely.

So in order to avoid the error give more time. like 60 seconds or 90 seconds.

Once roughly see how much time the page is taking to load completely by clicking on the **Submit** manually and note down the time.`(it may take long time if your internet connection is low).`

So after checking the time it is taking to load, Give that time in

`selenium.waitforpagetoload("time in m.sec")`.